# Headphones not working in ubuntu 13.06 - mac laptop

Tags: sound, mac, headphones

I have a mac laptop with ubuntu installed on it. The version of the ubuntu os is 13.06. It is an old generation mac book. The mic and the speaker works fine but when I plug in the headphones, no sound is detected in the headphones. The laptop definitely detects it because in the 'sound settings' program, the speaker icon/label switches to headphones, but sound continues coming from the speaker..

I saw a couple of posts re: alsa base conf edits but I could not get them to work. Can anyone be kind enough to help me get the headphones to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings=>Sound.  It should default to the output tab.  Inspect the window titled "Play Sound Through".  If you have two devices, one of the options should have "Headphones" in the description.  Be sure to plug in your headphones before you launch sound.  To the right you will see "Settings for Headphones" if your system is recognizing the headphones.

My Lenovo has both Speakers and Headphones options in the output section, My Asus has only Builtin Sound output, but recognized my headphones.  On my iMac I have both options Builtin Speakers and Headphones.  I think it depends on the sound card in your system.

You may want to consider searching for additional drivers in System Settings=>Software and Updates, click on the "Additional Drivers" tab and search for drivers.

Hope I haven't retraced your steps and that this will help.